# Projective family of hypersurfaces on curve admits some embedding?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f:X\to B$ be a projective family of hypersurface of type $(d,n)$ in on some curve $B$, i.e., $X\subset B\times \mathbb P^N$ is closed subscheme, and $f:X\to B$ is flat, with every fiber isomorphic to $n$-dimensional hypersurface of degree $d$. I want to know the following:

> Is it true that every fiber of $f$ admit an embedding to $\mathbb P^{n+1}$? i.e. there exists some other flat family $f':X'\to B$ with $X'\subset B\times \mathbb P^{n+1}$ a divisor, such that the two family $f$ and $f'$ are isomorphic?

I tend to believe this is not true, but I want to know a counter-example. Any comments would be helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by "$n$-dimensional hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^N$"?

Comment: Note that even a smooth curve of genus 2 cannot be (isomorphically) embedded into $\mathbb{P}^2$.

Comment: Dear @Sasha: I mean it is isomorphic to some hypersurface in $\mathbb P^{n+1}\subset \mathbb P^N$. Here $\mathbb P^{n+1}$ is a linear subspace of $\mathbb P^N$. Sorry for didn't make this clear.

Comment: @Sasha In your example, there is no embedding fiberwise, while I am considering the case where fiberwise embedding exists, but no global embedding.

Comment: Clearly, this is true locally on $B$, that is there is an open cover of $B$ such that on each of these you have such an embedding. It is also true that you can assume $X\subset B\times\mathbb{P}^{n+2}$. I do not know whether we can replace this with $n+1$.

Comment: On the other hand, $X$ can be embedded into a nontrivial $\mathbb{P}^{n+1}$-bundle.

Comment: @Akatsuki Let me understand correctly what you are asking first. Let $X\subset B \times \mathbb{P}^N$ be a closed subscheme such that every **geometric** fibres of the projection $X\to B$ is a hypersurface of degree $d$ in $\mathbb{P}^{n+1}$. Then, you wonder whether $X$ itself is a hypersurface of degree $d$ in $\mathbb{P}^{n+1}_B$ over $B$, right? Is that your question?

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar Yes. I assume $k=\bar k$ and by fiber I mean closed fiber. Sorry for did not make it clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible. For example, let $f \colon X \to B$ be a nontrivial etale double cover. Every fiber is a union of two points, so it can be embedded into $\mathbb{P}^1$ as a hypersurface. But there is no embedding $X \subset B \times \mathbb{P}^1$.

Indeed, assume $X \subset B \times \mathbb{P}^1$. Then $X$ is a divisor of relative degree 2 over $B$. Since $Pic(B \times \mathbb{P}^1) \cong Pic(B) \oplus Pic(\mathbb{P}^1)$, the corresponding line bundle can be written as $L \boxtimes O(2)$ for some $L \in Pic(B)$, so that $X$ defines a nonzero element in 
$$
H^0(B \times \mathbb{P}^1, L \boxtimes O(2)) = H^0(B,L) \otimes H^0(\mathbb{P}^1,O(2)).
$$
In particular, $H^0(B,L) \ne 0$.

On the other hand, we have a resolution
$$
0 \to L^{-1} \boxtimes O(-2) \to O_{B \times \mathbb{P}^1} \to O_X \to 0,
$$
which implies that
$$
f_*O_X \cong O_B \oplus L^{-1}.
$$
Since $f$ is etale and nontrivial, the line bundle $L^{-1}$ on $B$ is a nontrivial element of order 2 in $Pic(B)$.
In particular, $L \cong L^{-1}$ has no global sections.

Comment: Sorry I cannot follow your last line: why $L\cong L^{-1}$?

Comment: Because $L$ is a line bundle of order 2.

Comment: So the question should be, why it is of order $2$?

Comment: Since we started with an etale double covering, the multiplication map $(f_*O_X) \otimes (f_*O_X) \to (f_*O_X)$ restricts to an isomorphism $L^{-1} \otimes L^{-1} \to O_B$.

Comment: Oh I see. Many thanks! One more question (maybe not important): why you call the short exact sequence "resolution"? It is a resolution of $O_X$ or $L^{-1}\boxtimes O(-2)$? and in which sense?

Comment: $O_X$ is a coherent sheaf on $B \times \mathbb{P}^1$, the sequence is a locally free resolution for it.